# Asp.NET and Asp.NET Core Identity model over the same database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have two applications, one in asp.net and the other in asp.net core.  I want to share a common database, as well as the same login.  Ie, a user can register via asp.net application, and then their identity will be shared with asp.net core application.

Is this possible?  I notice that each have their own identity models, and I am looking for a way of sharing this, ie. some documentation to resolve this.

Looking for:
- Is this possible?
- Documentation and more information on implementation (how to)

Comment: The reason I have two applications, is because asp.net core application requires certain features and is eventually where I want my code.  asp.net application is still contains some webforms, which would require re-writing in .net core / razor etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am resolving by use of Identity Server, which both applications will hook into.  Will just take a bit of re-jigging.